# Can somebody identify this keyed connector?

Tags: connector

[image: xbox 360 dvd power connector]

Pin pitch is 0.079" for both row and column.

This looks like the two-row equivalent of the Molex Pico-blade.

I'm doing some rerouting for the power and data cables on my xbox 360 and I'm unable to figure out which digi-key part I need for this.

Namely, I'm looking for this connector's mating connector, but if I can figure out which series this, finding the mating connector would be significantly easier.

Comment: Are there any sort of logo or manufacturer mark anywhere on the connector?

Comment: Nope. I'm assuming Molex, but there's many thousands of Molex connector families and searching the digi-key catalog will take a long while.

Comment: You know you can sort the digikey catalog by pitch and row number, right?

Comment: Also, apparently *basically noone* makes 0.075" pitch connectors. There are 0.079" (or 2.00mm) pitch connectors. How precise is your measurement?

Comment: I eyeballed it with a digital caliper whose precision is +-0.002".

Comment: Also, I updated the post with what the closest family is (Molex Pico-blade). It's *not* the pico-blade because the blade connectors have 1 row and this has 2. Also, pico-blade is 0.049" and this is 0.079".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, just filtering by what you know about the connector yields about 20 possible options on digikey.

From the results, I think it's either a Hirose or JST connector.

[image]
Looks pretty close.

[image]
Also looks about right. However, it's black.

[image]
Is also promising.

One critical thing is that there may be markings *on the header for the cable, rather then the connector itself*. Since you say this is an xbox of yours, I assume you have both ends for the connector.

Considering that most of these headers are about 75 cents each, it may be perfectly reasonable to just buy a few of each, and try them.

---

The trick here is filtering.

Start at the digikey ["Rectangular Headers, male pins"](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/cat/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-headers-male-pins/1442547), and start filtering by what you know:

- 12 Pins
- "Connector Type" - "Header, Shrouded"
- "Pitch" - "0.079 (2.00mm)"
- "Number of Rows" - 2
- "Mounting Type" - "Through Hole"
- "In Stock" checked

And that gets you down to a grand total of ~20 options.

From that 20, there look to be two or three possibilities, and the rest can be ruled-out visually. The trick is to look for the indexing tab positions.

Comment: The board-side connector looks like the first of the three. Thanks!

Comment: @moshbear - No problem. I hope you understand the process I used to find the connector too. Digikey actually has one of the best "Filter by Characteristics" search systems I've used.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't know enough about connectors to filter by characteristic properly.

Comment: @Fake - Nice job!

Comment: @moshbear - Start with the things you do know, and see what you get out of the filter. Then browse the results you have to try and see what the further options mean.

Answer (score 0):

I built a power adapter(controller) for this about a year ago and the slip for the parts received is right here at my desk.

digikey #'s
    H2024-ND (socket) [HIROSE - DF11-12DS-2C]

```
H10233-ND (header) [HIROSE - DF11-12DP-2DSA(24)]
```

If you want to use the socket, then you'll have to order the pins separately.

Don't recall if you need an insertion tool.

I went with the header.  worked like a charm.